# Facebook Graph API request error when using HTTP POST / DELETE method

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, nullpointerexception, facebook-like

I'm developing an Android app which is integrated with Facebook SDK.

First I'm fetching the feeds of a Facebook page using Graph API, which is working fine. I want to allow the users to like & post comments against each feed.

I'm using the following code snippet for **Like**

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("access_token", access_token);

String response = null;
    String id = <Target Feed ID>;
    try {
        response = facebook.request(id+"/likes", parameters, "POST");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
        Log.i("FB Like Output", ""+response);
```

But I'm getting NullPointerException at the following line:

```
response = facebook.request(id+"/likes", parameters, "POST");
```

Please note that this error occurs **only when I'm using "POST" or "DELETE" as the 3rd parameter**. Instead if i'm using GET I get a proper response (which however, won't serve my purpose).

Also, I've added relevant permissions like **publish_stream**.

Is this the correct syntax for making a Synchronous request using HTTP POST method ?

```
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:130)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:68)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:186)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.requestImpl(Facebook.java:806)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:794)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.test.myapp.adapters.FacebookAdapter$1.onClick(FacebookAdapter.java:107)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-25 16:29:08.332: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This NPE happens before the request is even made. You should run the debugger from where you make the request, and make sure that what's being passed into the openUrl is not null.

Comment: @Ming Li ran the debugger but didn't find any null values being passed at that point...further this exception does not occur when I'm using GET as the 3rd param...Is this the correct syntax for making a Synchronous request using POST?

Comment: Where are you getting your access_token from when you call parameters.putString("access_token", access_token)? From the NPE, Util.java:186 is when the code tries to url decode the access token, and that's where it's getting the null pointer.

Comment: I am getting the access_token after login which I'm storing in shared preferences like this: SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit(); String access_token = facebook.getAccessToken(); editor.putString("access_token", access_token); editor.commit(); Thereafter i'm retrieving it from the shared preferences. I ran the debugger and found that it is not null.

Comment: what is weird about this is that I don't the NPE when I replace the "POST" with "GET". If there is a NULL value it should be there irrespective of that (3rd param).

Comment: In that case, you should set a breakpoint right before where the NPE happens (in the Utils class), and check what is actually null.

Comment: Also, what version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Facebook SDK 3.0.1 / Android 4.0.3

Comment: In that case, you really shouldn't be using the deprecated Facebook class and associated methods. Use the Session class and Request class instead.

Comment: any link for the Session class?

Comment: This is the Session class: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session

Comment: Also, this is a useful tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/ and here's an upgrade guide from 2.0 to 3.0 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.0/

Answer (score 0):

As indicated on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/,

**Like the given object (if it has a /likes connection**)

[image]

And you're not able to find /likes connection on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

You can't like a  fanpage, and the code cause the problem

```
 String id = <Facebook Page ID>;
```

Comment: I'm able to do a POST request to like any feed from this particular page using the Graph API Explorer tool. So, in this case that's probably not the issue

Comment: No, i means your code  "String id = <Facebook Page ID>;" indicated you're doing 'Like the page', instead of 'Like the feed of the page'. Should be  "String id = <your target post_id>"